# Number of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b<n$ and such that $\gcd(a,b,n)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $n$ be a positive integer.
What is the number of pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that $a+b<n$ and such that $\gcd(a,b,n)=1$?

I know that the number of positive integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,n)=1$ is just $\varphi(n)$. Maybe we can express the answer for my question above in terms of $\varphi(n)$ and other arithmetic functions.

Comment: Where does this problem arise?

Comment: In studying to count the number of positive integer solutions of some algebraic equations. Might be not a very fruitful direction of research, but for some cases, it gives a nice alternative proof of some fun facts about arithmetic functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is [A000741](https://oeis.org/A000741) the number of compositions of $n$ into $3$ ordered relatively prime parts.  Write $c=n-a-b,$ so that $(a,b,c)$ is a composition of $n$.  Some of the scripts given on OEIS seem to relate to the divisor function, but I don't know any of the languages, so I can't be sure.